# Is there a R function to bring my date columns in 2 different colums month and daying

Tags: r

extracting date information 2010/05/01 in R to create new column

I modified the attribute in Date format
right now my format is M%/Day%/Year%

b<-as.Date(Date)

expected result 2010/02/01
result  0002-02-20

Answer (score 2):

We need to specify the `format` assuming that the format is 'Year' followed by 'month' and 'day'

```
as.Date(Date, format = "%Y/%m/%d")
```

Without the `format`, it assumes the format to be "%Y-%m-%d" by default

Comment: and Then ,How will I extract the month and Year please.

Comment: @memile After the `as.Date`, you can use `format(as.Date(Date, format = "%Y/%m/%d"), "%m")`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
# Create a date string
dateString <- "2010/05/01"

# Convert the date string to a Date object
date <- as.Date(dateString, format="%Y/%m/%d")

# Extract the year and month
year <- format(date, "%Y")
month <- format(date, "%b")
```

More information about date formats in R [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/date-formats-in-r/)

Comment: Ah sorry @akrun, I didn't see you comment with the `format` code.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the package `lubridate` helpful for this type of thing.

```
library(lubridate)

my_date <- "2010/05/01"
```

Convert to a date from format year/month/date using function `ymd()`

```
> ymd(my_date)
[1] "2010-05-01"
```

Extract the day using the function `day()`

```
> day(ymd(my_date))
[1] 1
```

Extract the month using the function `month()`

```
> month(ymd(my_date))
[1] 5
```